# Crear CSV desde una lista de Diccionarios y entrecomillar los datos

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, csv, diccionarios

Tengo una lista de diccionarios asi:

```
lotes = [{'lote': '30045612', 'producto':'nombre_producto1'},
         {'lote': '30045613', 'producto':'nombre_producto2'},
         {'lote': '30045614', 'producto':'nombre_producto3'},
         {'lote': '30045615', 'producto':'nombre_producto4'}
        ]
```

y necesito exportarla a un CSV, y para poder procesarlo después, debe quedar con todos los datos entrecomillados.

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
if len(lots_not_checks) > 0:  # validación previa necesaria para mi code
    with open('csv_lots_not_checks.csv', 'w') as csv_lots_not_checks:
        fieldnames = ['Lote', 'Producto']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_lots_not_checks, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(lots_not_checks)
```

esto me devuelve un CSV asi:

```
lote,producto
30045612,nombre_producto1
30045613,nombre_producto2
30045614,nombre_producto3
30045615,nombre_producto4
```

pero necesito que llegue asi:

```
"lote","producto" 
"30045612","nombre_producto1"
"30045613","nombre_producto2"
"30045614","nombre_producto3"
"30045615","nombre_producto4"
```

Comment: @eyllanesc La falta de seriedad la tienes tú. Si analizaras bien las preguntas, te darías cuenta de que que el código que señalo si tiene que ver mucho con el tuyo, pues en mi primera pregunta, no tenía código alguno, mas ahora utilicé el tuyo, que dicho sea de paso, solucionó el 90% del asunto. Si analizaras, te darías cuenta de que cuando hablo de adaptar el código, lo que hice fue cambiar el nombre de tu variable `nuevos_lotes` a `lots_not_checks ` y `csv_file ` a `csv_lots_not_checks`.

Comment: Si analizaras te darías cuenta de que salté el paso de cambiar el nombre de la clave porque esta ya se llamaba así. '¿Siendo un sitio de ayuda, no deberías tener paciencia con quienes apenas programamos un 'Hola Mundo'? Pero no, lo primero que buscas es que marquen tus soluciones como correctas... Te queda grande el sitio.

Comment: Me disculpo con la comunidad, pero no creo que esa deba ser la forma de "ayudar", puesto que muchos tenemos mucho que hacer para que otros vengan a querer hacernos perder tiempo queriendo mostrar  sus medallitas. Vine buscando ayuda, no un currículum.

Comment: Te dije que no funcionó.

Comment: Si lo he entendido esto se consigue simplemente con         `writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_lots_not_checks,
                                fieldnames=fieldnames,
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                                quotechar='"'
                                )`. Dónde `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` es a clave. Eso si `fieldnames` no coincide con las claves de tu diccionario (empiezan en minúsculas) y tu lista es `lotes` no `lots_not_checks`.

Comment: @FJSevilla funcionó.